# Scala: Ordering[Int].lt invocation fails for reflective method call

Tags: scala, reflection, scalatest, mirror

I'm playing with Scala reflection and ScalaTest. I've a method defined as follows in an object `Ch2`:
`def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean`

The following test fails as described in the comment:

```
"Method isSorted" should "return true for a sorted array" in {
    val methods =
      Table(
        ("method"),
        ("isSorted")
      )

    val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
    val mod = ru.typeOf[Ch2.type].termSymbol.asModule
    val mm = m.reflectModule(mod)
    val obj = mm.instance
    val im = m.reflect(obj)

    forAll(methods) { (m: String) =>
      val isSortedMethod = ru.typeOf[Ch2.type].decl(ru.TermName(m)).asMethod
      val isSorted = im.reflectMethod(isSortedMethod)

      // Fails at runtime with 'missing parameter type for expanded function'
      isSorted(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), Ordering[Int].lt(_, _))
    }
}
```

Of course, I could replace `Ordering[Int].lt` with `(x: Int, y: Int) => x < y` and it'd work but I'd rather use what's already provided instead of rolling my own.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler cannot infer type `A` in your call. Try to make the call without reflection.

You should specify type during call like

```
isSorted(Array(1, 2, 3, 4), (x: Int, y: Int) => Ordering[Int].lt(x, y))
```

Comment: "> Try to make the call without reflection."
That'd defeat the purpose of learning. Besides, consider the case where I implement the method in several different ways (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34960325/scala-how-do-i-use-foldleft-with-a-generic-array)). Instead of writing identical test cases for each method, I could use a data table and just invoke each method reflectively. The i/p and o/p are the same so it's a perfect candidate for data tables.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar You understood me in a wrong way. I did not advise you to fix your problem by not using reflection. I advised you to check how to do your call without reflection to see the problem you are facing. And then you can use reflection. Also please see edit, I have change the proposed solution to the one that works with reflection

Comment: I got around the issue with this: `val lt = Ordering[Int].lt(_, _)` and then `isSorted(Array(1,2,3,4), lt)`