# Scala: How do I use foldLeft with a generic array?

Tags: arrays, scala, generics, foldleft

I've this method:

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
    val sorted = for (it <- as.sliding(2))
      yield {
        if (it.length == 2) ordered.apply(it(0), it(1))
        else true
      }

    sorted.find(!_).isEmpty
}
```

What I'd like to do is use `foldLeft`and apply the binary operator. However, `foldLeft` requires an initial value and I don't know what initial value I can provide without knowing the real type of `A`.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7852918/1153435

Comment: @Eduardo already did. There's no consensus in that thread what to do for breaking. Some say `break` is the best thing in Scala since sliced bread, others think it's evil as it throws an exception under the hood.

Comment: Have you tried `reduceLeft`?

Comment: @Jus12 yes and it doesn't work. The signatures don't match. `reduceLeft[B >: A](op: (B, T) => B): B`, in my case the binary op is `(A, A) => Boolean`

Comment: Yeah, I think the only way to get that signature right is to go with something like `aggregate(true)((b,x) => b && ordered(x(0),x(1)), (_ && _))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're doing can be simplified.

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  if (as.size < 2)
    true
  else
    as.sliding(2).find(x => !ordered(x(0),x(1))).isEmpty
}

isSorted: [A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean)Boolean

scala> isSorted( Array(2), {(a:Int,b:Int) => a < b} )
res42: Boolean = true

scala> isSorted( Array(2,4), {(a:Int,b:Int) => a < b} )
res43: Boolean = true

scala> isSorted( Array(2,4,5), {(a:Int,b:Int) => a < b} )
res44: Boolean = true

scala> isSorted( Array(2,14,5), {(a:Int,b:Int) => a < b} )
res45: Boolean = false
```

Or, perhaps a little more concisely (but not necessarily easier to understand):

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  if (as.size < 2)
    true
  else
    !as.sliding(2).exists(x => ordered(x(1),x(0)))
}
```

**UPDATE**

OK, I think I've got the concise prize nailed.

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean =
  as.isEmpty || as.init.corresponds(as.tail)(ordered)
```

Comment: Speaking of conciseness and laziness, and borrowing your idea, I could do - `(as.isEmpty) || as.view.sliding(2).find(it => !ordered(it(0), it(1))).isEmpty`

Comment: Yes indeed, although the `isEmpty` test will miss the single-element array.

Comment: Ugh yes, I meant to use `as.size < 2` but somehow ended up with `isEmpty`.

Comment: You know, after looking it over, I'm not sure that `view` is offering much benefit.  `sliding()` produces an iterator.  Is iterating over a view really better/faster?

Comment: No it's not, and using a view as in my comment actually runs into the bug [SI-6709](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6709). Iterator is fine, or I need to use `as.toIndexedSeq.view.sliding`. Good catch.

Comment: Does the `find` work lazily? (or does it still iterate though the entire array?)

Comment: Many [collection methods](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/5adc400f5ece336f3f5ff19691204975d41e652e/src/library/scala/collection/Iterator.scala) that return Boolean or Option use a lazy, or terminate-early, algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

For initial value for foldLeft you could use head of your input array. However foldLeft is not a good choise to check if array is sorted, since you should terminate method when first unsorted element found but foldLeft will traverse whole array

**Edit:**

I would use the combination of zip with tail and exists:

```
isSorted(...) = 
   if (as.isEmpty) true
   else !as.zip(as.tail).exists { case (a,b) => !ordered(a,b)}
```

Comment: I can't use head if the array is empty. If I've to put in an `if-else`, I'm writing more code.
As for traversal, what do you suggest using?

Comment: And I'm looking for a more concise solution, hence the question.

Comment: Is `zip` lazy? Otherwise this solution is concise alright but still traverses the whole array.

Comment: Good point. zip is not lazy here, so view should be applied before zipping

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the other answers, you probably do not want to iterate through the entire array, but rather terminate the moment you find an unordered pair. So, how about this?

```
def isSorted[A](as: Array[A], ordered: (A, A) => Boolean): Boolean = {
  var sorted = true
  val ita = as.sliding(2)
  while (sorted && ita.hasNext) {
    val it = ita.next
    sorted = if (it.size > 1) ordered(it(0), it(1)) else true
  }
  sorted
}

val a = Array(1, 3, 2, 4, 5)
val b = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

isSorted[Int](a, _ < _) // returns false
isSorted[Int](b, _ < _) // returns true
```